# Can't understand the bulletproof @font-face CSS rule

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

Before marking this as duplicate please read through my doubts. I searched thoroughly on the web(**particularly stackoverflow**) & couldn't get the doubts cleared. This question may seem lengthy at a glance but it contains crucial issues which others also want to know.

I'm trying to gain a slightly deep knowledge in the bulletproof `@font-face` rule and the people out there are confusing me. Please suggest me on this guys.
So, here's the latest bulletproof code as suggested by **Font-Spring** (http://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax/) along with the IE9 compatibility mode issue solved:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

The one without the **IE9 Compatibility Mode Fix**, also by **Font-Spring**(http://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/), looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Currently, I'm reading a book "The Book Of CSS3" by Peter Gasston.
It follows the bulletproof rule with **IE9 Compatibility Mode** fix as stated by the Font-Spring. He says that the rule with a query string `?` in the second `src` property is responsible for IE9 Compat. Mode fix. But, font-spring holds the first `src` property responsible for IE9 Compat. Mode fix. I'm not able to learn this syntax without understanding it completely.

My serious issues are rather smaller. First of all I wanna know if only the `?#iefix` can prevent the parsing error or it could be something like `?iefix` (without `#`) or it could be `?xyz` or `?#abc`. Is it necessary to write exactly `?#iefix`?

Secondly,

- I can't feel how this `@font-face` rule gets parsed, how
  IE8 decides which of the `src`
  properties is to be used for `eot` font. And if IE9 has no issues with parsing even in the
  compatibility mode, how will it decide which font-format to use? Will
  the IE9 in compatibility mode break on query string font url & if not
  then why not?
- Can somebody tell me if I look at the whole bulletproof rule stated
  above, how IE8, IE9 in compatibility mode, IE9 in normal mode & other
  browsers will parse it? How will a browser decide from several fonts which one to use if it supports majority of them. What is the order in which the browser looks `url` values and `src` properties?
- Is it like that an alone `src` property without any `local()` and
  `format()` values and with a correct `eot` format will be accepted by IE8 and it will not go further
  to the next `src` property in which other formats are defined? Or will it still go to the next `src`
  property & download fonts from there?
- If there will be a query string (`?`) in the next `src` property,
  will IE8 (IE9 in compatibility mode considered as well) download the `eot` font two times? And if there will be no
  query string, then will it accept the `eot` font from first property
  and won't break or will it break & don't apply any custom defined
  font even from the first `src` property?

Also, does IE9 in normal mode support `eot` format?
Won't the bulletproof syntax still work if I just remove the whole query string declaration like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE6-IE8 as well as IE9 Compat. Mode */
src: url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Won't the above still work in all the possible cases? IE6-8 will have the first `src` along with the IE9 in compatibility mode and all other browsers will follow the rest of rules.

Would the above rule suggested by me work same with the `local()` value as follows:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE6-IE8 & IE9 Compat. Mode */
src: local('MyWebFont'), /* To fix IE6-IE8 and IE9 Compat. Mode */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Whether in IE8 or in IE9 compatibility mode, `local()` value will make them go away.. Would IE9 in normal mode use `eot` or `woff` from above rule?? If it does use `eot`, can we make a slight change to first `src` property like this:

```
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
```

IE9 will ignore this property as it contains `eot` and move on further to use `woff`, am I right? Also, if I again make a change to this rule itself like this:

```
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
```

Would IE9 now use `eot` format or still go on with `woff`?

This is all I want to know and yes I think these questions definitely need an answer.

Comment: I feel a strong urge to edit your question and add "[citation needed}".

Answer (score 5):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

This is simply a trick to workaround the various IE* inconsistencies, with the first src you satisfy IE9, so if your viewer has this browser he gets this font, the second src doesn't overwrite the first one because IE9 isn't able to parse the `'webfont.eot?#iefix'` string

About the second src of the rule: that is the "old" bulletproof syntax and you are already familiar with it. Please note that, as said in the blog post of Fontspring about the hardened rule, Microsoft fixed the bug in IE9 when using IE7 and IE8 render modes but they didn't actually fixed IE7 and IE8 so you still need this trick for these browsers.

A clarification about `local()`: this tell to the browser to use a certain local (i.e. on the pc of the viewer of the page) available font, if your viewer doesn't have it installed then he'll not be able to see the right font, for more info about this you can check this: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/#smiley

Comment: First of all thank you for even replying to my ridiculous question. I still have a little doubt about do we really need the line with '?#iefix...', coz' I don't think so, as IE9 in compatibility mode takes on the first src so should IE6-IE8... isn't it? The first src property doesn't include any format() or local() construct which aren't recognized by IE6-IE8, so this line alone should work in both the cases. What do you say?

Comment: You are welcome @GauravRockrIf you are on IE9 the second src alone won't work (since the IE6-IE8 fix ), so you need the first one. But the  Well, actually I think the best answer is

Comment: Sorry I posted the comment before I ended it and now I can't modify it, here is the correct one: You are welcome @GauravRockr, if you are on IE9 the second src alone won't work (since the IE6-IE8 fix doesn't work on IE9), so you need the first one too. But the first one works only on IE9 so you need both to satisfy every IE (of course, if you don't have to support legacy IE, you can skip the ?#iefix). Anyway, the best way to understand this is to just try it. Take some virtual machines with the different IE versions and see how it works :)

Comment: ya I know that the ?iefix doesn't work for IE9 Compat Mode but as the first property `src: url('webfont.eot')` doesn't contain multiple fonts and local() and format() constructs, shouldn't it alone work for IE6-8 as well?

Comment: No, actually it doesn't. IE6-IE8 need the fix (because of a bug, it is not intended) while IE9 doesn't understand it so, if you want to support all the IE range, you need both the src properties